# Getting max count from mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have table as follows

```
+------+------+------+----------+
| vno  | ino  | cno  | quantity |
+------+------+------+----------+
| V1   | I1   | C1   |      150 |
| V1   | I5   | C1   |      100 |
| V1   | I5   | C4   |      150 |
| V2   | I2   | C1   |       50 |
| V2   | I2   | C4   |      500 |
| V2   | I2   | C5   |      500 |
| V2   | I3   | C4   |      300 |
| V2   | I6   | C4   |      300 |
| V3   | I1   | C1   |       10 |
+------+------+------+----------+
```

I am trying to retrieve the customer who has bought maximum quantity

following is my query

```
SELECT Delivery.cno, sum(Delivery.quantity) as totalQuantity From Delivery group by Delivery.cno
```

this query give following result

```
+------+---------------+
| cno  | totalQuantity |
+------+---------------+
| C1   |           310 |
| C4   |          1250 |
| C5   |           500 |
+------+---------------+
```

then, I modified it to get the max total Quentity,

```
SELECT B.cno,max(B.totalQuantity) as maxQuantity from  
(SELECT Delivery.cno, sum(Delivery.quantity) as totalQuantity From Delivery group by Delivery.cno )  B order by B.cno;
```

it gives me following result

```
+------+---------------+
| cno  | totalQuantity |
+------+---------------+
| C1   |           1250|
```

this answer is totally wrong as C1 has count of 310, not 1250

could anybody help me to understand what is wrong with my query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is working because MySQL doesn't throw errors in case there are columns in the `select` that are not either aggregated or `group`ed `by`, so it manages to display `B.cno`, but result is incorrect.

In case total sum is unique you can use the following: order the records in the descending order by total `sum` and get the first record (with maximum `totalQuantity`):

```
select Delivery.cno
     , sum(Delivery.quantity) as totalQuantity
from Delivery
group by Delivery.cno
order by totalQuantity desc
limit 1
```

Otherwise you can use the query above to find the maximum `totalQuantity` and then check for each grouped `Delivery.cno` if it's `sum(Delivery.quantity)` is equal to maximum using a `having` clause.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. could you help me understand why the query i have used is not working with mysql. is it because of the limitation of the mysql db

Answer (score 1):

The total sum might not be unique. Try:

```
select Delivery.cno, sum(Delivery.quantity) as totalQuantity
from Delivery
group by Delivery.cno
having totalQuantity = max(totalQuantity)
```